# How to find unique lines from each file given 3 text files

Tags: command-line, text-processors

I have 3 text files with some unique IDs and I want to keep only unique IDs in each text file. Let's say there are 3 files (A, B and C). If an ID of "abc" appears in A and B, it needs to be removed from both files.

The files are sorted and under 1MB in size and IDs are alpanumeric characters. Also within each file, there is no duplicate.

Is there a way to do this just by using command line tools in Linux or Mac? I was thinking of writing a code initially but wanted to ask first. Thanks!

Comment: Are the files ordered, and if not, can they be re-ordered?  Also, how big are these files/ how important is efficiency. I could script a solution using sort, uniq and grep, but it would be a multistage process. This probably does not matter for files up to a few megs in size, but might not be ideal for very large ones. Relatedly are there.likely to be a lot if dups, and are the IDs purely alphanumeric?

Comment: @davidgo thanks. I edited my question and tried to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- the text files have a single ID per line
- each line only contains an ID and no other text
- the IDs are not repeated within a file
- it is OK to reorder the output file (sort it)
- execution efficiency isn't important
- IDs are alphanumeric

```
$ cat A B B C C | sort | uniq -u >A.uniq
$ cat B A A C C | sort | uniq -u >B.uniq
$ cat C A A B B | sort | uniq -u >C.uniq
$ mv A.uniq A
$ mv B.uniq B
$ mv C.uniq C
```

The 'cat' command concatenates the listed files together.  The first file is the one I want to strip of duplicates.  The next files are the potential duplicates I want to strip out.  I add in two copies of each of these files to guaranty that they are duplicated and will be stripped out.

Next, I 'sort' these files together alphabetically.  This results in any duplicated IDs being on neighboring lines in the sorted output.

The 'uniq' command with the '-u' option only outputs lines that are uniq.  If two or more of the same ID appear on neighboring lines in the input, nothing is output.

The '>' writes the output to a new file called 'A.uniq'

If you wanted to do the opposite and generate a list of all of the IDs that are duplicated in the 3 files, you could do something like:

```
$ cat A B C | sort | uniq -d >duplicates
```

The 'uniq' command with the '-d' flag only outputs a line if it is repeated two or more times in the input.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this as I posted my own answer but this is not what the OP asked - he wanted the duplicates removed from the existing files, not to produce a new list that was free of duplicates. (This requirement is clearly stated at the end of both paragraphs)

Comment: Per @davidgo 's comment, I modified the suggested CLI commands to include 'mv' commands to replace the original files with the new uniq output.

Comment: @jbarlig this still misses the point.  (As per the first paragraph) I expect the INPUT should be 3 files, and the output should be those same 3 files but without duplicates.   I expect your A.uniq B.uniq and C.uniq would all be identical.

Comment: @davidgo I think you need to take a closer look at what is happening here.  A.uniq will contain only the IDs that are unique to file A.  B.uniq will only contain IDs that are unique to file B.  File C.uniq will only contain IDs that are unique to file C.  It is crude, but it accomplishes the task.

Comment: ok, yes. I see.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the distraction - I came up with the following script  (documented) -

```
#! /bin/bash

SOURCEFILES="./existing/list1.txt  ./existing/list2.txt  ./existing/list3.txt"

# First find a list of duplicate files.  We do this by catting all files and finding where there are lines that are not unique

# $DUPLICATES will be a space seperated list of duplicate IDs

DUPLICATES=$( cat $SOURCEFILES | sort | uniq -d )
echo "Duplicates Found for removal: " $DUPLICATES

# Convert list of duplicates into a pipe seperated list
# Commented out version assumes all ID's are all the same length, so it would break if one is ABC and another is ABCD 
#DUPLICATES=$( echo $DUPLICATES | tr ' ' '|' )

# This version translates the duplicate REGEX to say that each line is complete 
# ^ means start of line and $ means end of line.

for each in $DUPLICATES
do
    DUPLIST="$DUPLIST^$each$|"
done

# Remove trailing "|" from DUPLIST
DUPLICATES=$( echo ${DUPLIST::-1} )


# Go through each file, removing duplicates 
for each in $SOURCEFILES
do
    mv $each $each.old
    egrep -v "$DUPLICATES" < $each.old > $each
done
```